# Pay Later not showing

Tags: civicontribute, paylater

For some reason after updating to CiviCRM 5.29.1 the "Pay Later" option (which is selected) is no longer working on DarrylWPerry.com/donate

EDIT: if I turn off HTTPS/SSL protections it appears.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: we have just had a site report that even though the form is set up for Pay Later, that after selecting a price option the 'pay later' option does not show alongside the other payment options. This was a 5.28.1 site. but could be same issue. will be looking in to it on Monday

Comment: is there an update?

Comment: I was wrong. the issue was not that client was not seeing Pay Later. apologies for the mix up. i had only seen the ticket, not actually checked the issue.

Comment: It's definitely a mixed-content issue where all the files in the js folder are being served without ssl. What do you have in admin - system settings - resource urls? Anything that specifically says http? Also check civicrm.settings.php.

Comment: Thanks, civicrm.settings.php still had http instead of https... corrected it, and it works without issue!

Answer (score 2):

The option should appear once you select the amount. If it does than set default one of the option from amounts tab of contribution page

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the SSL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GW0i.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUvvH.png